# How to apply a filter only if one of the checkboxes is clicked using react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i want to apply filter only when one of the checkboxes is clicked using react and typescript?

what i am trying to do?

there is a table with some data and a filter icon on the page. when user clicks the filter icon he sees two checkboxes namely "source on", "source off".

1. now initially when no checkbox clicked the table shows all data meaning data with both source on and source off like point 4 below.
2. when user clicks source on checkbox only then table shows data with source on
3. when user clicks source off checkbox only then table shows data with source off
4. when user clicks both the checkboxes table shows all the data with source on and source off like point 1.

now the query to backend should be send like so ?source=true  if checkbox with source on clicked. ?source=false sent with source off clicked.

now if user clicks both checkboxes or doesnt click both checkboxes no filtering should be applied.

Here the table is using react-table.

below is the code,

```
const sourceFilterOptions = [
    { value: 'true', id: 'on', label: 'Source On'},
    { value: 'false', id: 'off', label: 'Source Off'}
]

const filterFields: any = [
    {

        name: 'source',
        type: 'checkbox',
        defaultValue: '' //not sure what to be set initially when no checkboxes 
        // clicked
        label: 'Source',
        options: sourceFilterOptions,
    }
]

// this is the graphql query
query fetchData(
    $source: String //not sure what type should be given
) {
    some(
        source: $source
    ) {
          //some data
       }
   }
   
const MainComponent: React.FC<SomeProps> = ({}) => {
    const filtersValues = useFiltersValues({filterFields}); 
    
    const variables = React.useMemo(
       () => ({
           ...queryOptions.variables,
           ...filtersValues,
    }),
        [queryOptions.variables, filtersValues]
    );
    const { data, loading, error } = fetchDataQuery({
        ...queryOptions,
        variables,
    });

    const { tableData } = React.useMemo(
        () => ({
            tableData: data || [],
    }),
       [data]
    );

    return( 
        <TableWithFilters filterFields={filterFields}>
            <Table
                data={tableData}
                columns={columns}
             />
         </TableWithFilters>
     );
 }


 const TableWithFilters: React.FC<TableWithFiltersProps> = ({
     filterFields,
     ...props
 }) => {
     const {
         isOpen: filtersIsOpen,
         isActive: filtersIsActive,
         toggleIsOpen: toggleFiltersIsOpen,
         handleSubmit: filtersHandleSubmit,
         defaultValues: filtersDefaultValues,
         initialValues: filtersInitialValues,
     } = useFilters({ filterFields, path, toggleState });

     return (
         <Formik
             initialValues={filtersInitialValues}
             onSubmit={filtersHandleSubmit}
         >
             {formikProps => {
                 const filtersIsDefault = isEqual(
                     formikProps.values,
                     filtersDefaultValues
                 );
                 const filters = (
                     <Filters
                         fields={filterFields}
                         isDefault={filtersIsDefault}
                         onResetClick={filtersOnReset}
                         {...formikProps}
                     />
                 );
                 return (
                     <Main
                         leftPanelOpen={filtersIsOpen}
                         onLeftPanelCloseClick={toggleFiltersIsOpen}
                         leftPanelContent={filters}
                         {...props}
                     >
                 </Main>
             );
         }}
     </Formik>
 );};
```

As seen from above code i have set two checkboxes and passing the default Values for checkboxes (initially they are unchecked)

now the question is i dont know how to set the initial values and default values to the checkbox meaning such that i send either true or false to query.

if none selected no filters applied and if both selected no filters applied.

could someone help me with this as how to do it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend coding in a way that, when a user checks one the other option becomes unchecked automatically. You can attach `ref`s to the checkboxes and manipulate their checked value accordingly. Like this:

```
   const checkBox1 = useRef(null);
   const checkBox2 = useRef(null);

   render(
      <>
      <input
         type="checkbox"
         ref={checkBox1}
         onChange={(e)=>{
            if(e.target.checked) checkBox2.current.checked = false;
         }}
      />
      <input
         type="checkbox"
         ref={checkBox2}
         onChange={(e)=>{
            if(e.target.checked) checkBox1.current.checked = false;
         }}
      />
      </>
   )
```